# Multiple Inner Joins with Create view

Tags: sql, join, view

Creating the View Table in SQl server 2012 there is any error pls correct it

```
create view Invoice as 
Select CustomerInfo.C_Name,CustomerInfo.C_ID,OrderDetails.O_ID,OrderDetails.O_name,ProductDetails.Price
from OrderDetails
inner join ProductDetails 
on OrderDetails.P_Model=ProductDetails.P_Model
inner join CustomerProduct
on OrderDetails.O_Id=CustomerProduct.O_Id
inner join CustomerInfo`on CustomerProduct.C_Id=CustomerInfo.C_Id



enter code here`

CustomerInfo =C_id primary  key
OrderDetails=O_id primary key ,P_model foreign key
ProductDetails=P_model  primary key 
CustomerProduct= C_id,O_id foreign key
```

Comment: there is no quotes at this place

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have overlooked a single quote here:

CustomerInfo`on